# Running 'pebble install' gives error on Mac

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I am trying to run `pebble install` on Mac.  I have already installed the Pebble SDK, and I can start the Pebble simulator...  I cannot however start the phone simulator.

When I `cd`'d into the directory of my app and ran `pebble install`, it returned :

```
[INFO    ] Starting Pebble emulator...
[INFO    ] Starting phone simulator...
[ERROR   ] Could not connect to phone at localhost:12342. Ensure that 
'Developer Connection' is enabled in the Pebble app.
```

I don't have the Pebble app on my phone, nor do I have the Pebble watch yet.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance,
Fjpackard.

Comment: This happens to me occasionally on Linux. If you Ctrl+C and try again do you get the same error? Which version of the SDK are you using? What if you manually add either `--emulator aplite` (Pebble) or `--emulator basalt` (Pebble Time) to the command?

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  I did try this already, but it didn't work.  I have actually figured it out now, so I will post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured this out !  I already had Python 3.4 installed, so even though I install Python 2.7, it got a bit messed up :/  I just uninstalled both versions of Python, then reinstalled 2.7 and it works perfectlyl ! =)

Comment: I just had python 2.7 (installed with `brew install python`) and it's not working (tried also to reinstall it)